# XSD with different namespaces support

Tags: xml, xsd

Good day!

I generated xml file as follows:

```
<object xmlns:el="elements_namespace" xmlns:vlprops="vl_props_namespace"
    xmlns:vlsvc="vl_svc_params_namespace" xmlns:p="general_params_namespace">
    <el:BTN vlprops:link="../clientdb/#abn/fl" vlprops:btnType="hist"
        vlprops:linkInTab="true" p:nm_title="some_text"
        p:vl_order="0" p:nm_service="null" p:pr_visible="true" p:nm_endpoint="null"
        p:nm_logical_id="null" p:nm_description="null">
        <vlprops:linkCols><![CDATA[[]]]></vlprops:linkCols>
        <p:window_BTN />
    </el:BTN>
    <el:GRID vlprops:rows="15" p:nm_title="null" p:vl_order="3"
        p:nm_service="some_text" p:pr_visible="true" p:nm_endpoint="CLDB"
        p:nm_logical_id="some_text" p:nm_description="some_text">
        <vlsvc:vars><![CDATA[["vl_params"]]]></vlsvc:vars>
        <vlsvc:consts><![CDATA[{"in_function": "mdTotalTags"}]]></vlsvc:consts>
        <p:columns_GRID>
            <el:GRDCOL vlprops:rows="15" p:nm_title="null" p:vl_order="0"
                p:nm_service="null" p:pr_visible="true" p:nm_endpoint="null"
                p:nm_logical_id="null" p:nm_description="some_text">
                <vlprops:linkCols><![CDATA[["id_client"]]]></vlprops:linkCols>
            </el:GRDCOL>
            <el:GRDCOL vlprops:rows="15" p:nm_title="some_text"
                p:vl_order="1" p:nm_service="null" p:pr_visible="true"
                p:nm_endpoint="null" p:nm_logical_id="null" p:nm_description="null"></el:GRDCOL>
            <el:GRDCOL vlprops:rows="15" p:nm_title="some_text" p:vl_order="2"
                p:nm_service="null" p:pr_visible="true" p:nm_endpoint="null"
                p:nm_logical_id="null" p:nm_description="null"></el:GRDCOL>
            <el:GRDCOL vlprops:rows="15" p:nm_title="some_text"
                p:vl_order="3" p:nm_service="null" p:pr_visible="true"
                p:nm_endpoint="null" p:nm_logical_id="null" p:nm_description="null"></el:GRDCOL>
            <el:GRDCOL vlprops:rows="15" p:nm_title="some_text" p:vl_order="4"
                p:nm_service="null" p:pr_visible="true" p:nm_endpoint="null"
                p:nm_logical_id="null" p:nm_description="null"></el:GRDCOL>
            <el:GRDCOL vlprops:rows="15" p:nm_title="some_text" p:vl_order="5"
                p:nm_service="null" p:pr_visible="true" p:nm_endpoint="null"
                p:nm_logical_id="null" p:nm_description="null"></el:GRDCOL>
            <el:GRDCOL vlprops:rows="15" p:nm_title="some_text"
                p:vl_order="6" p:nm_service="null" p:pr_visible="true"
                p:nm_endpoint="null" p:nm_logical_id="null" p:nm_description="null"></el:GRDCOL>
            <el:GRDCOL vlprops:rows="15" p:nm_title="some_text почта"
                p:vl_order="7" p:nm_service="null" p:pr_visible="true"
                p:nm_endpoint="null" p:nm_logical_id="null" p:nm_description="null"></el:GRDCOL>
            <el:GRDCOL vlprops:rows="15" p:nm_title="some_text" p:vl_order="8"
                p:nm_service="null" p:pr_visible="true" p:nm_endpoint="null"
                p:nm_logical_id="null" p:nm_description="null"></el:GRDCOL>
        </p:columns_GRID>

        <p:footDetail_GRID />
        <p:rowDetail_GRID />
    </el:GRID>
</object>
```

Now I need to generate XSD scheme, I've googled some info in internet, came across some examples. All of them had just one namespace. Like

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.my.com/book" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="book">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="author" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType> 
    </xs:element>      
</xs:schema>
```

It contains xs: namespace only, I wonder if I can make one xsd file that would embrace all namespaces in my xml

```
(
el="elements_namespace" 
xmlns:vlprops="vl_props_namespace"
xmlns:vlsvc="vl_svc_params_namespace"
 xmlns:p="general_params_namespace"
)
```

If this is possible could you give me  a little example with my xml? thanks in advance

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but why have elements and attributes of said elements in two separate namespaces?  Namespaces are overkill in most cases to begin with, why double up the bloat?  You may also consider not including "null" attributes.

Comment: I had to write a parser that would create neccessary insert statements, because of some issues i had to separate the items with different namespaces. Also I have to keep a track whether the value is null, is not null, or was not passed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML Schemas are typically arranged with one schema for each namespace, but the schemas can import each other.

For example, for the root element, a first schema with no target namespace can be defined, which imports the `el` schema. It then can refer to elements defined in the `el` schema with `ref` attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:el="elements_namespace">
    <xs:import namespace="elements_namespace" schemaLocation="el.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="object">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="el:BTN"/>
                <xs:element ref="el:GRID"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The same mechanism for importing and referring to element and attributes can be reused in all schemas, except that the other schemas will have a target namespace.

There is one point that usually brings confusion:

- `name` attributes have **local names**, without prefix, because the elements being declared live in the schema's target namespace (for this, make sure that `elementFormDefault` is `qualified`, except if the entry schema that has no target namespace).
- `ref` attributes must have QNames, with prefix. You thus need to bind prefixes accordingly, as above.

Finally, it is advisable to use URIs for namespaces. The XML Names specification requires this, even though in practice many processors actually treat them as strings and won't complain.